# Forgot password workflow in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In general, how does the forgot password is implemented in Xamarin forms. I know for web applications, password rest link is sent and user is logged-in after changing the password.

For mobile apps, how do I invoke reset password screen when they click on the link. If it is not possible, do we need to create a website just for password reset.

Another possibility is have a token generated automatically and embed in the login link sent by mail and open the mobile app and automatically login.

I would like to know standard way of doing in Xamarin forms and appreciate if could provide references to articles/libraries.

Comment: How is the password stored?  Is it in a local db?  Or stored on a remote server?

Comment: Authentication is implemented in remote server using Web API.

Comment: then it would make sense for the server that handles auth to also handle password reset.  Whether you handle this in-app or via a webpage is a matter of preference - there is no "correct" answer

Comment: Yes, I am new to Xamarin. I would like to know how it can be implemented in-app. Because once reset email is sent, if I redirect to web page, user gets disconnected with mobile app.

Comment: @Sunny You server will send an email which will have a email reset link. Then in xamarin form you would have to set up applinks. Check this link 
https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/08/applinks-in-xamarin-forms/